# Remove last n characters of filenames for all files in a directory

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

How can I remove the last 12 characters of all files' filenames in a certain directory via Terminal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
for i in ?????????????*; do echo mv -i "$i" "${i%????????????}"; done
```

remove `echo` for actual action. *Check for same output filename for multiple source files.*

Also you could use parameter expansion replacement pattern:

```
for i in ?????????????*; do echo mv -i "$i" "${i/????????????}"; done
```

---

Using `rename` (`prename`), from that directory:

```
rename -n 's/.{12}$//' *
```

This will rename all files and directories, if you want to do for only files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '?????????????*' -exec rename -n 's/.{12}$//' {} +
```

This will do dry-running, remove `-n` for actual action:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '?????????????*' -exec rename 's/.{12}$//' {} +
```

*Again this could result in a race condition, make sure you check the output from the dry-running carefully.*

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention to ignore the file-extension, so there is a cleaner solution to my problem. I eventually appended that via pyRenamer without difficulty as I'm exclusively dealing with files of the same type.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `rename`. Check it's installed:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

From inside the directory, run:

```
rename -n 's/(.*).{12}/$1/' *
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the files. Replace `{12}` with `{whatever number of characters you want to delete from the end of the name}`.

#### Explanation:

- `s/old/new/' replace` old`with`new`
- `(.*)` save any number of any characters...
- `.{12}` the last twelve characters whatever they are
- `$1` the characters saved with `()`

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` you can use [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

**Single line**

```
for filename in *; do newname=${filename:0:-12}; mv "$filename" "$newname"; done
```

**Multiple lines with comments**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop through all files in the directory
for filename in *; do

    # Remove the last 12 characters from the name
    newname=${filename:0:-12}

    # Rename the file by moving it
    mv "$filename" "$newname"

done
```